# Postgresql on AWS Fargate with an EFS volume results in a "Broken pipe" error

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, aws-fargate, amazon-efs

I am trying to run a Postgresql replica DB on Fargate. For storage I mounted an EFS volume and put the the DB on via the `PGDATA` environment variable. When the Fargate task starts the sync with the main DB starts and everything seem to work fine for some minutes until:

```
FATAL:  connection to client lost
LOG:  could not send data to client: Broken pipe
```

This error then occurs every other minute until the health checks fail eventually.

Anyone has an idea what does this error mean in this context? And/or how to get fix it?

Comment: I am wondering if the issue is due to the fact that you are hammering your DB that is on an EFS file system (not something that we'd recommend doing in general). It would be interesting to see if you could use (for test purposes) instead the [local ephemeral storage Fargate makes available](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/fargate-task-storage.html) to see if you still see the problem. Again, this is just to rule out that EFS is the offending part of the configuration. The local storage is ephemeral so don't use it for a DB replica.

Comment: Using the Fargate task storage everything works perfect. At least until the storage is full ;)

Comment: Yeah... what I feared. There are a couple of things you could try playing with. Assuming this is on the EFS end you may want to try tuning the file system with the knobs made available there. I doubt this will change for the better the outcome. Another thing you could *try* doing is deploying a larger task (assuming you are not already). Larger tasks have larger network specs and that *may* help. However I fear this is more because of the way NFS works (and that does not make it a GREAT candidate for DBs).

Comment: For the records, we are working on [larger storage support](https://github.com/aws/containers-roadmap/issues/384) for Fargate. This however won't resolve for the ephemerality problem.

Comment: EFS is slow, even when compared to NFS, and while you [_can_ use NFS with Postgres](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/creating-cluster.html#CREATING-CLUSTER-FILESYSTEM), most of the DBAs that I know will look at you strangely if you do. While I'm a fan of Fargate, I think this is one of those times where EC2 is a better choice ... assuming that you have good reasons not to use RDS.